# how to pass parameter with @url.action to controller

Tags: url, razor, controller, html-helper

i have following code snippet i want to pass data-id="0" with my @url.action , how can i do this

```
<a class="v-patient pointer" data-id="0" href="@Url.Action("View1", "Task")">View Patient</a></td>
```

my task controller

```
public ActionResult View1(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If is was an `ActionLink` you would do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View1", "Task", new {id=0}, null);
```

So in your case, using `Url.Action()` it would be:

```
href="@Url.Action("View1", "Task", new {id=0})"
```

Which in your sample is:

```
<a class="v-patient pointer" data-id="0" href="@Url.Action("View1", "Task", new {id=0})">View Patient</a></td>
```